# Constructing a sequence of bits in java

Tags: java, binary, bit

I'm having trouble getting a bit to work properly in java6...I'm trying to write a compression program that will write bits to a compressed file...so for example a common letter such as "e" might just be the binary sequence "101" in ascii

I think the `fileOutputStream.write(int)` method is what I'm going to want to accomplish this, but how to I represent a sequence of bits as in int?

Comment: Do you need it bit-wise? meaning that you could put 2 'e's into the stream and still have 2 bits left of that byte? then you would need to define how many bits per information etc. Take a look at bit shifting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). And then write a full byte array using [`FileOutputStream#write(byte\[\])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) like that:

```
fileOutputStream.write(myBitSet.toByteArray());
```

Comment: BTW, I gave links to Java 7 docs, but it is valid in Java 6 as well.

Comment: Ummm, that can't be the simplest way to write `e` to a stream. ;)

Comment: Im unfamiliar with the (byte\[\]) notation, and I know Bitsets are vectors, is that a special notation of vectors?

EDIT: I just see what I did sorry im silly :P

Comment: @PeterLawrey - of course, but this is a way to "represent a sequence of bits"

Comment: @SetSlapShot - `byte[]` means byte array.

Comment: @MByD, Just thinking about what might be the most suitable for the OP's level of understanding. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - You are absolutely right. I tend to answer the sentence ending with question mark directly too much :)

Answer (score 0):

101 is the ascii value for 'e'

All you have to is write it

```
FileOutputStream fos =
fos.write('e'); // writes 101 which is the ascii for 'e'
```

Comment: That actually writes '00000101'. Don't know if OP wants that :-/

Comment: In binary, but `e` is `(byte) 101` in ascii rather than `0b101`